# Has ISV revenue share changed from 15% to 25%?

Tags: appexchange

I was reading through this link and was surprised to see that all partners including ISV and OEM are now at 25% revenue share: https://partners.salesforce.com/s/ISVPartnerProgramGuidePY2018.pdf

Is this correct or am I reading this wrong?

Answer (score 0):

No. See the FAQ at the end where it says:

> Q: Are Checkout partners subject to the 25% PNR terms?
>
> A: No, partners that transact with Checkout as a payment processing option are not subject to the 25% PNR. The percent of net revenue for Checkout partners at this time is 15%, unless otherwise communicated on the Partner Community.

Comment: Got it, but what if you are a partner that doesn't use Checkout because you invoice clients directly?  Is that some sort of negotiated rate?

Comment: I would recommend you get clarification from your Account Rep or ask this in the Partner Community where you'll get an official answer.